Finding an explicit optimal map using Brenier's Theorem
I have the following set up:
$$
X, Y = [-1,1] \\
\text{Probability Measures } \mu, \nu \text{ with densities:} \\
f(x)= \frac{15}{4}x^2(1-x^2) \\
g(y)=\frac{3}{4}(1-y^2) \\
\text{Cost function: } c(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2
$$
I'm told that I can assume that the optimal map is smooth and linear. The goal now is to find the optimal map transport mass between these two spaces via Brenier's Theorem. My only problem is that I'm defficient in my knowledge on ODEs, so its very likely that I'm missing something.
This is how far I've gotten: Notice that we can simplify the push forward equation to:
$$
f(x)=g(T(x))T'(x)
$$
Now by the theory of ODEs, if we integrate on both sides over the $X$ domain, I think this should give something of the form of a cubic condition, right? But how should I proceed to solve this?
Edit: Actually, I believe the question is less about ODEs, and more about solving a polynomial. The cubic I computed is:
$$
\lambda^3 - 3\lambda + 2 = 0
$$
whenever $T(x)=\lambda x$, since $T(x)$ is linear.
We can use the trigonometric solution (or just observe) to find that this polynomial admits two solutions: $\lambda = -2$ and $\lambda = 1$

The optimal map cannot be linear. In fact, $T \colon X \to Y$ needs to be a bijection, since your measures have full support. Thus, only $T(x) = \pm x$ would be allowed, but this is not feasible.

@gerw thanks for the feedback. that makes sense. how would you proceed with the question then? I just realised that the map need not be linear in the outline of the question. But I had assumed most monge transport problems only cared for the linear map anyways (which I am definitely mistaken)

@gerw i thought about what you said and i sketched out the densities of f(x) & g(x). what i realised is that I need a function that has some sort of polynomial behaviour and is bijective (as you suggested). so setting $T(x)=\lambda x^3$ seems like a good candidate for now

never mind, that makes no sense
